# What is the cause for getting a noClassDeffound error when I run my java application?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

When I run my program, I am getting the following error, I do not have any idea what this error means? Does anyone have any ideas?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: program/pkg7/Program7 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: program.pkg7.Program7
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: programja.pkg7.Program7.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What does your Java source code look like?

Comment: Would you like to see it? I will post it if yes.

Comment: Please mention more about your environment. How do you execute the program?

Comment: This is a common problem.  The cause is that you've not got the relevant classes on your runtime classpath.

Comment: @Karki, it might help solve your problem. :)

Comment: @Karki - the source code is probably irrelevant to this problem.  The problem is most likely in the way that the program is being run.  (The only relevance of the source code is that it would confirm what you should be using as the "class name" argument on the `java` command line.)

Comment: Note that this error might result from attempting to run the class from the `pkg7` directory, rather than the parent of the `program` directory.

Comment: @ Stephen, let me see if I have any logic errors. And, blamonet, the code is one and half pages long. I am new to this site and do not know I can do post it or not?

Comment: @ Andrew, then how can fix this and make it run?

Comment: 1) Show the directory structure that exists between where the command is run, and the location of the class file.  2) show the command used to launch the app. -- copy/paste both as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15994853/edit).

Comment: Well, you don't have your app setup properly. Could be missing an import statement or you are missing the classes folder, etc...

Show us your code and how you have setup the app.

Comment: @Karki `NoClassDefFoundError` has nothing to do with 'logic errors'. It is entirely about your deployment and your command line.

Answer (score 1):

There is something fishy about your Question.  The diagnostics show two distinct exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: program/pkg7/Program7 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: program.pkg7.Program7
```

and then the message at the bottom says:

```
Could not find the main class: programja.pkg7.Program7.  Program will exit.
```

Note that the program name is different.

But ignoring the inconsistencies (caused by bad copy-and-paste?), the most likely causes are one of the following:

- The fully qualified name of the class you are trying to start is not "program.pkg7.Program7" ... but (I'm guessing) "pkg7.Program7"
- The execution classpath is incorrect when you launch the command, and the JVM cannot locate the class as a result.  (The classpath tells Java where to look for the classes it needs to load.)

In the absence of more information from you about how you are running the program, the best I can suggest is that you *carefully* read the Oracle documentation on how the classpath works:

- ["Setting the classpath"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)
- [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I create a new project and copy the code?

Comment: *"Can I create a new project and copy the code?"* - I don't know whether it would help.  You might just end up making the same mistake that you are currently making.  If you explained what tools you were using and how you are running the program, we could give you better advice.

Comment: @ Stephen, I am using the NetBeans IDE 7.3, and running the program from the main method by calling methods which are coded under the class "program 7".

Comment: @Karki - *"... and running the program from the main method by calling methods which are coded under the class "program 7""* - I don't understand that part of your comment.  You can't "call" a method in an IDE.  You are launching the program ... and you need to explain clearly HOW you are launching the program.

Comment: @Karki - Besides, I don't use NetBeans and I'm not familiar how it launches programs.

Comment: @Karki - I suggest that you EDIT the Question, to add a **complete and accurate description** of how you are launching the program.  Maybe someone who uses NetBeans can help you.  Alternatively, launch the program from the command line ... using the `java` command and the information about classpaths that I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this may be your problem.

You class **Program7** has the package called **program.pkg7**. And you are doing **java Program7** from inside the directory **pkg7**

Solution is:

Get back to your compiled class root directory and run like:

```
java -classpath . program.pkg7.Program7
```

Regards,
Ravi